# How to fill in a table from a input using jQuery and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html-table

I have been trying to fill in a table based on the search result using jQuery and ajax but I can't make it work.

Here is the html code:

```
<form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="livsmedelsSokOrd">Livsmedel</label>
        <input type="search" class="form-control" id="livsmedelsSokOrd" placeholder="t ex makaroner">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="sok-button">Sök</button>
</form>
<table id="tabell" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Livsmedel</th>
            <th>Energi (kcal/100g)</th>
            <th>Kolhydrater</th>
            <th>Protein</th>
            <th>Fett</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("#sok-button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url      : "getlivsmedel.php",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        data     : {
            namn: $('input#livsmedelsSokOrd').val()
        },          
        success  : function(response){
            var foodArray = response.livsmedel;
            for (var i = 0; i< foodArray; i++){
                var namn         = response[i].namn;
                var energi       = response[i].energi;
                var protein      = response[i].protein;
                var fett         = response[i].fett;
                var kolhydrater  = response[i].kolhydrater;
                $("#tabell").append(
                    "<tr><td>"+ namn +"</td><td>"+ energi +"</td><td>"+ protein +"</td><td>"+ fett +"</td><td>"+ kolhydrater +"</td></tr>"
                );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

After I press the search button I can see in the javascript console that it loads the php but it doesn't fill the table, and I have tried everything I can think about.

Comment: How the received data looks like? The one thing I can tell is that in the `for` loop part should be - `i < foodArray.length`. Also, for large amount of data, avoid DOM modifications inside loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop has 2 problems.

You need `i < foodarray.length` instead of `i < foodarray` and `response[i]` should be `foodarray[i]`

Try adjusting to:

```
for (var i = 0; i< foodArray.length; i++){
     var namn = foodArray[i].namn;
   ......
```

You should be seeing errors in browser console that `response[i]` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You should be appending the `<tr>` to `<tbody>` instead of `<table>`. **$("#tabell").append** should become **$("#tabell tbody").append**